# Javascript: Changing the class of the first element in a div

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to change the class of the first div.
e.g.

```js
var div1 = element.getElementsByClassName("parent")
div1.children[0].setAttribute("class", "1 2");
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="1">Test</div>
  <div class="1">test</div>
  <div class="1">test</div>
</div>
```

But class doesnt change. Any idea why?
thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
div1.children[0].className = "1 2";
```

Or

```
div1.children[0].classList.add('1');
div1.children[0].classList.add('2');
```

You should pick better class names btw!

Edit:

```
var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0];
div1.children[0].classList.add('1');
div1.children[0].classList.add('2');
```

Comment: Yeah, just used the numers for this example here. It doesnt work with className either.
http://jsfiddle.net/ezn1rg9q/

Comment: @Django I changed my answer. Try again. You weren't getting the `div1` correctly

Answer (score 0):

Jquery way:

```
$(".parent > div:first").addClass("1 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// getElementsByClassName return an array (it is a collection)
var allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("root");

// in the array i need the first 
var myFirstElement = allDivs[0];

// i want first child
var myFirstChild = myFirstElement.children[0];

myFirstChild.className =  'b' ;
```

```css
.a{ border : solid 1px red }
.b{ border : solid 1px blue }
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="a">Test</div>
  <div class="a">test</div>
  <div class="a">test</div>
</div>
```